# Exporting from WPF to Excel

Tags: c#, wpf, excel, winforms

I created a WinForm that adds data from textboxs to a List and then when the form closes, exports that data to an excel spreadsheet. I'm in the process of trying to convert my WinForm to a WPF, and the code is no longer working. I'm not getting any errors, it just isn't creating the spreadsheet. Am I missing something here?

```
protected void OnFormClosing(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if(signees.Count > 0)
        {
            initExcelSheet();
        }

    }


    public void initExcelSheet()
    {

        EXL.Application oXL;
        EXL._Workbook oWB;
        EXL._Worksheet oWS;
        EXL.Range oRng;
        oXL = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
        oXL.Visible = true;

        //Get a new workbook.
        oWB = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Workbook)(oXL.Workbooks.Add(""));
        oWS = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Worksheet)oWB.ActiveSheet;

        oWS.Cells[1, 1] = "First Name";
        oWS.Cells[1, 2] = "Last Name";
        oWS.Cells[1, 3] = "Email";
        oWS.Cells[1, 4] = "Expected Graduation Date";
        oWS.Cells[1, 5] = "School";
        oWS.Cells[1, 6] = "Major";
        oWS.Cells[1, 7] = "Favorite Languages";

        oWS.get_Range("A1", "G1").Font.Bold = true;
        oWS.get_Range("A1", "G1").VerticalAlignment =
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlVAlign.xlVAlignCenter;

        int count = 2;
        foreach(Person x in signees)
        {
            oWS.Cells[count, 1] = x.firstName;
            oWS.Cells[count, 2] = x.lastName;
            oWS.Cells[count, 3] = x.email;
            oWS.Cells[count, 4] = x.gradDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
            oWS.Cells[count, 5] = x.schoolName;
            oWS.Cells[count, 6] = x.fos;
            oWS.Cells[count, 7] = x.fcl;
            count += 1;
        }


        oRng = oWS.get_Range("A1", "G1");
        oRng.EntireColumn.AutoFit();
        try
        {
            oWB.SaveAs(fileName(school, DateTime.Now));
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Console.Write(e.ToString());
        }

        oWB.Close();
```

Comment: Are you sure you want to use Office Interop? You can run into some issues with having Excel running in the background due to not cleaning up properly. And it requires Excel be installed on the machine. You might have better luck using a managed library such as EPPlus, NPOI, or Open XML SDK.

Comment: Or just output a CSV file.